# using glob with lerna --scope filtering by package name or directory name

Tags: glob, lerna

When using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna), I'm having trouble creating a glob pattern to find multiple packages with a common naming convention. Am I supposed to be searching against the directory path or the name field in the package.json?

Directory Structure

```
packages/
    prefix-module-identifier1
    prefix-module-identifier2
    prefix-module-identifier3
    prefix-platform-identifier1
    prefix-platform-identifier2
```

Package Naming convention

```
@nameSpaceScope/prefix-module-identifier1
@nameSpaceScope/prefix-module-identifier2
@nameSpaceScope/prefix-module-identifier3
@nameSpaceScope/prefix-platform-identifier1
@nameSpaceScope/prefix-platform-identifier2
```

I'd like to run a command for just the *module* packages or just the *platform* packages. In these examples I'm looking for just the module packages
I've tried globs for:

```
--scope *module*
--scope **/*module*
--scope packages/*module*
--scope @nameSpaceScope/*module*
--scope @nameSpaceScope/+(*module*)
```

The closest glob that gets anything is `--scope packages/*module*`, but it only finds the first module.

My lerna config

```
{
  "packages": [
      "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Did you try `lerna bootstrap --scope prefix-platform-*` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hexagon,

I just checked in my own lerna monorepo and found that using the `--scope` flag in a lerna command definitely refers to names as defined in **package.json**.

See here for details on [how the --scope flag works in lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/core/filter-options#--scope-glob).

So, looking at how you have named packages above, to get just your *module* packages, the following glob patterns that you have tried *should* work...

`--scope @nameSpaceScope/*module*`

`--scope @nameSpaceScope/+(*module*)`

I even went so far as to try them out using https://globster.xyz/

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding another option for multiple services:

`--scope={service1,service2,...}`

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked: adding quotes because `@` is used as part of a pattern parsing.

```bash
lerna run --scope '@org-name/*' build
```